# Installing ESP-IDF by Visual Sutdio in Win10 meets some problems

Tags: c++, visual-studio, installation, esp32, esp-idf

I've already installed the offline installer from https://dl.espressif.com/dl/esp-idf/, and then chose the "use existing setup" option from the extended program ESP-IDF, and then the output window shows the following information:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

```
Building wheel for psutil (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
```

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for psutil
ERROR: Could not build wheels for psutil, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I just want to know how to fix this to start my ESP32 development.  Any suggestions may works for me, thanks all of u

Comment: What's the version of your visual studio? Did you try to update the Microsoft C++ Build Tools?

Comment: I think the Espressif toolchain is only supported in Visual Studio Code, not in Visual Studio

Comment: Errm, the very first message tells you what to install and from where to download it.

Comment: I've successfully fixed that problem, I just restarted the software and then the ESP-IDF can be used to compile and flash the program to the board, sorry for not providing any useful information

Comment: @Cisco Hi, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider adding an answer and changing its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :) It will also help others to solve the similar issue.